# How to count the number of characters entered?

Tags: c++, pointers

My assignment is

> In C++, use pointer to count the number of characters user entered. Print the output on screen

Here is what I have done. I do not know how to count the characters I entered.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int string[20] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };
    int sum = 0;
    char a;
    cout << "Enter less than 20 characters(no space) : ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        cin >> a;
        string[i] = a;
        if (string[i] != 0)
            sum = sum + 1;
        else
            break;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "The number of characters in " << *string << " is " << sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a string directly. And display its length. (or say what the problem is, you can't display a integer array like this).

Comment: If you have questions about homework assignments, your teacher or instructor is the best resource for getting help. That's what they're being paid for, that's their job.

Comment: You have a variable named `string` - but it's an array of `int`s, which doesn't in any way resemble a string.

Comment: BTW, the usual definition of a *string* is zero or more *characters*, not `int`.

Comment: Also, the assignment says to use a pointer.  You don't have any pointers in your code.  Definitely talk with the instructor and get some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the requirements, you'll need to use a pointer.

```
int main()
{
  static const size_t MAX_CHARS = 20;
  char text[MAX_CHARS] = {0};
  std::cout << "Enter up to 20 characters, no spaces: ";
  size_t quantity = 0;
  char c;
  while (std::cin >> c)
  {
     if (quantity >= MAX_CHARS) break;
     text[quantity++] = c;
  }
  // Count the characters using a pointer: 
  if (quantity < MAX_CHARS)
  {
     text[quantity] = '\0';
  }
  else
  {
     text[MAX_CHARS - 1] = '\0';
  } 
  quantity = 0;
  char * pointer = &text[0];
  while (*pointer != '\0')
  {
    ++quantity;
    ++pointer;
  }
  std::cout << "Characters entered: " << quantity << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

I guess this is an exercise to understand pointers.

Otherwise, I suggest using `std::string` and `std::string::length()`.

Comment: But after I entered your program, the results it shows are always“Characters entered: 0”

Comment: The variable _quantity_ needs to be initialized as 0. Otherwise, it might lead to non-deterministic behavior.